# How can I generate a thumbnail image for video files (mp4) in TYPO3 filelist?

Tags: image, typo3, video-thumbnails, typo3-12.x

Here is a screenshot of my TYPO3 filelist. I run TYPO3 12.4:

[image: Screenshot of mp4 files in TYPO3 Filelist]

If thats not possible, does anybody know if I can replace the ugly error image of TYPO3 with an own preview image? Maybe in the Installation-Wide Options? Thanks for you help!

Comment: For newly uploaded files you can use this event to generate thumbnails https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Events/Events/Core/Resource/AfterFileAddedEvent.html

For already existing files/MP4 perhaps you could write a UpgraeWizard